# How can I make my popup appear smoothly after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

The popup shall appear and cover the full screen after 5 seconds smoothly using the CSS3 transition property and opacity, however it appears all at once.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dnvk87xL/

```js
var element = document.getElementById("popup");

var t=setTimeout(openPopUp,5000);
function openPopUp() {
  element = document.getElementById("popup");
  element.style.display = "block";
  element.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

```css
#popup{
  position: fixed;
  height:100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="popup">
    I'm gonna appear smoothly after 5 seconds
  </div>
  <p> Website content </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Display" is not animatable CSS property. Instead, try using "Visibility".

```js
var element = document.getElementById("popup");

var t=setTimeout(openPopUp,5000);
function openPopUp() {
  element = document.getElementById("popup");
  element.style.visibility = "visible";
  element.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

```css
#popup{
  position: fixed;
  height:100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="popup">
    I'm gonna appear smoothly after 5 seconds
  </div>
  <p> Website content </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set `display: block;` from the beggining? Add a z-index to move it to the background too and change it after. Check it out:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("popup");

var t=setTimeout(openPopUp,5000);
function openPopUp() {
  element = document.getElementById("popup");
  element.style.opacity = "1";
  element.style.zIndex  = "1";
}
```

```css
#popup{
  position: fixed;
  height:100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.7s;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="popup">
    I'm gonna appear smoothly after 5 seconds
  </div>
  <p> Website content </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solves the animation, but content of webpage is covered with invisible popup from the beginning. You can't select the text "Website content", and if there was some button or link, it would not be clickable...

Comment: @Ondra Koupil , that's right. I updated my answer with a fix (using z-index) to avoid such problems.

Comment: I should have specified this when I asked the question, but doing that would make my website useless for 5 seconds because of the 0 opacity div making the user unable to click on content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery function `FadeIn` in your `setTimeout`

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    element.FadeIn('slow');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I guess nowadays is using CSS animation almost always preferable to javascript animation...